# Can I plot a graph with two Y axis from different Data Frames?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph of a stock price with its Google Trends interest, but I am unable to plot them in the same graph as the error says:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (2094,) and (261,)

This is what I have:

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df = web.DataReader('ITUB4.SA', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-31', end='2020-07-21')
data = df.filter(['Close'])
print(df)

trend_list = ['ITUB4']
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['ITUB4'], geo='BR')
df_divo = pytrend.interest_over_time()
df_divo = df_divo.filter(['ITUB4'])
print(df_divo)

x = df.index
y1 = data['Close']
y2 = df_divo['ITUB4']
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
curve1 = ax1.plot(x, y1)
curve2 = ax2.plot(x, y2)
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `x` and `y1` are both from `df` and have 2094 rows. However, `y2` is from `pytrend` and only has 261 rows, which is why you're getting the `ValueError`.
- The x-axis of the plot is in a datetime format. There is no need to plot `df_divo.ITUB4` with `df.index`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()

# get yahoo data
df = web.DataReader('ITUB4.SA', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-31', end='2020-07-21')

# get ITUB4 data from pytrends
trend_list = ['ITUB4']
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=trend_list, geo='BR')
df_divo = pytrend.interest_over_time()

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, 'Close', data=df, label='Close')
ax.plot(df_divo.index, 'ITUB4', data=df_divo, label='Interest over Time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!